# how to hide the table if there is no data and show the form using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Iam getting the records in tabular format and displaying the data in front end but if there is no data i need to hide total table including table headings.here is my code.

```
<table style="width:87%;">
    <tr class="spaces">
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th style="width:20%;">Rent Earned</th>
        <th>House</th>
        <th>Address of Property</th>
    </tr>
    <?php include "rentaldetails.php";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['rental_annual_rent'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['rental_tax_paid'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['rental_town'];?>
        </td>
        <td style="width:21%;"><a class="button add" onClick="document.location.href='income_tax.php'">Edit Details</a></td>
        <td style="width:21%;"><a class="buttons delete" href="deleterental.php?id=<?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete">Delete Property</a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
</table>
<form method="POST" action="details.php">
<th>Address Line</th>
<td><input type="text" name="address" value=""  /></td>
<th>Town/City</th>
<td><input type="text" name="city" value="" /></td>
<button type="submit"  class = "medium" style="background-color: #a9014b;float:left;">Save</button>
```

I need to hide these total table if there is no data in database and should display the form.

Comment: Why not place the entire table in a `if ($result)` in php?

Comment: Hi Can anyone tell me if the table data is empty i need to display a form how can we show a form if the table data is empty.my form starts once the tabel s completed as i updated my ode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php include "rentaldetails.php";

if(mysql_num_rows($result)== 0){
    $dispNone = "display:none";
}else{
    $dispNone = "display:block";
}

?>


<table style="width:87%;"  style="<?=$dispNone?>">
    <tr class="spaces">
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th style="width:20%;">Rent Earned</th>
        <th>House</th>
        <th>Address of Property</th>
    </tr>
    <?php include "rentaldetails.php";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['rental_annual_rent'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['rental_tax_paid'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['rental_town'];?>
        </td>
        <td style="width:21%;"><a class="button add" onClick="document.location.href='income_tax.php'">Edit Details</a></td>
        <td style="width:21%;"><a class="buttons delete" href="deleterental.php?id=<?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete">Delete Property</a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
</table>
```

EDIT :

PHP:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)== 0){
    $dispNone = "display:none";
    $dispForm = "display:block";


}else{
    $dispNone = "display:block";
    $dispForm = "display:none";
}

?>
```

HTML :

```
<form style="width:87%;"  style="<?=$dispForm?>">

</form>
```

EDIT 2:

```
<table  style="width:87%;<?=$dispNone?>">

<form  style="width:87%;<?=$dispForm?>">
```

Comment: Hi Can you tell me if the table data is empty i need to display a form how can we show a form if the table data is empty.

Comment: Okie Riyaj i will be checking

Comment: it is not hiding table heading if there is no data

Comment: Please do EDIT2 changes.There is two style attribute .So its getting first one

Comment: Heading <h3>,addsalary button and next is not hiding

Comment: is is not ur current html post

Answer (score 2):

You can use if else condition to show and hide total table
like below:

```
<?php 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ ?>
  <table style="width:87%;">
      <tr class="spaces">
          <th>S.No.</th>
          <th style="width:20%;">Rent Earned</th>
          <th>House</th>
          <th>Address of Property</th>
      </tr>
      <?php include "rentaldetails.php";
                  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {?>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>
          </td>
          <td>
              <?php echo $row['rental_annual_rent'];?>
          </td>
          <td>
              <?php echo $row['rental_tax_paid'];?>
          </td>
          <td>
              <?php echo $row['rental_town'];?>
          </td>
          <td style="width:21%;"><a class="button add" onClick="document.location.href='income_tax.php'">Edit Details</a></td>
          <td style="width:21%;"><a class="buttons delete" href="deleterental.php?id=<?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete">Delete Property</a></td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
  </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `if else` [statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

```
if(!empty(mysql_fetch_array($result))){
   //Here your datatable 
}else{
   //echo 'No Data';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:


    <?php 
include "rentaldetails.php";
    if(!empty(mysql_fetch_array($result))){?>
    <table style="width:87%;">
    <tr class="spaces" >
    <th>S.No.</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Rent Earned</th>
    <th>House</th>
    <th>Address of Property</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['rental_annual_rent'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['rental_tax_paid'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['rental_town'];?></td>
    <td style="width:21%;"><a class="button add" onClick="document.location.href='income_tax.php'">Edit Details</a></td>
    <td style="width:21%;"><a class="buttons delete" href="deleterental.php?id=<?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete" >Delete Property</a></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     }
    ?>   
    </table>
 <?php   } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Can you tell me if the table data is empty i need to display a form how can we show a form if the table data is empty.

Comment: Please do not encourage the use of officially deprecated mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("#mytable td").length == 0){
    $("#mytable").hide();  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" style="width:87%;">
    <tr class="spaces">
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th style="width:20%;">Rent Earned</th>
        <th>House</th>
        <th>Address of Property</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysql_num_rows()` for hiding the `<table>` it will check no's rows before fetching the records as:

```
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
?>

<table style="width:87%;">
    <tr class="spaces">
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th style="width:20%;">Rent Earned</th>
        <th>House</th>
        <th>Address of Property</th>
    </tr>
        <?php include "rentaldetails.php";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['rental_annual_rent'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['rental_tax_paid'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['rental_town'];?>
                </td>
                <td style="width:21%;"><a class="button add" onClick="document.location.href='income_tax.php'">Edit Details</a></td>
                <td style="width:21%;"><a class="buttons delete" href="deleterental.php?id=<?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete">Delete Property</a></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
</table>
<?
}
?>
```

**Side Note:**

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extension because `mysql_*` is deprecated and close in PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide your entire table you can just use this 
PHP code in your HTML table tag and it should hide your entire table if your query does not return any results.

```html
<?php echo (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)?'visible':'hidden'; ?>
```

So basically your entire code to hide the table would be like below:

```html
<table <?php echo (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)?'visible':'hidden'; ?>  style="width:87%;">
    <tr class="spaces">
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th style="width:20%;">Rent Earned</th>
        <th>House</th>
        <th>Address of Property</th>
    </tr>
    <?php include "rentaldetails.php";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['rental_annual_rent'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['rental_tax_paid'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['rental_town'];?>
        </td>
        <td style="width:21%;"><a class="button add" onClick="document.location.href='income_tax.php'">Edit Details</a></td>
        <td style="width:21%;"><a class="buttons delete" href="deleterental.php?id=<?php echo $row['house_details_id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete">Delete Property</a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
</table>
<form method="POST" action="details.php">
<th>Address Line</th>
<td><input type="text" name="address" value=""  /></td>
<th>Town/City</th>
<td><input type="text" name="city" value="" /></td>
<button type="submit"  class = "medium" style="background-color: #a9014b;float:left;">Save</button>
```